# To compare two directories only for file names and file numbers in Unix

Tags: unix

In Unix, I have two directories on 2 different servers. Say, on **Server1**, I have **EXPORT directory** with many sub directories and many files. And on **Server2** I have **IMPORT directory** with many sub directories and many files. I have to prepare a batch monitoring **in Unix** to check if the files of **Server1 EXPORT directory** are available or not at **Server2 IMPORT directory**. So I have to compare only the file names and total file number. I don't need to compare the file data.

Comment: Please, post what you've got so far

Answer (score 0):

You can compare two directories by diff command as

```
diff -r directory1/ directory2/
```

For more details please check diff manual

```
man diff
```